# Does liquid have an "or if blank?"-type filter?

Tags: liquid

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<a href="...&user_name={{customer.name}}&...">Click me.</a>
```

but sometimes `customer.name` might be blank. Not `null`, but Ruby's version of `blank?` (eg. an empty string `""`). In that case I want to use `customer.email`.

In a perfect world, liquid would have an `or_if_blank` filter that did the following:

```
<a href="...&user_name={{customer.name | or_if_blank: customer.email }}...">Click me.</a>
```

But it does not. Any easy way to hack this? I'm very new to liquid so the answer could be staring me right in the face even though I've been pouring over [these docs](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers) for 15 minutes.

And BTW, I know I could solve this by changing the structure of the `customer` object that I'm passing into Liquid, but unfortunately I can't do that very easily so I'm hoping to find an easy out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following format to change html based on the value of customer.name:

```
{% if customer.name %}
<a href="...&user_name={{customer.name}}&...">Click me.</a>
{% else%}
<a href="...&user_name={{customer.email}}&...">Click me.</a>
{% endif %}
```

You can read more about if statements with liquid here: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#if--else

Comment: Yes it look like based on Liquid's current API that this is the only way to accomplish this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `default` filter:

```
<a href="...&user_name={{customer.name | default: customer.email }}...">Click me.</a>
```